# Openlayers pop-up FeatureSelected doesn't invoke even FeatureClicked works well

Tags: openlayers-2, popup, actions

My code snippet is:

//Vector Layer with listeners:

```
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Kuzzular");

    vectorLayer.events.on({
        'featureselected': function(evt) {
            var feature = evt.feature;
            var popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("popup",
                    OpenLayers.LonLat.fromString(feature.geometry.toShortString()),
                    null,
                            feature.attributes.name+"<br>"+feature.attributes.address+"<br>"+feature.attributes.speed + " km/h",
                    null,
                    true,
                    null
            );
            popup.autoSize = true;
            popup.maxSize = new OpenLayers.Size(1600,1600);
            popup.fixedRelativePosition = true;
            popup.relativePosition = "tl";
            popup.panMapIfOutOfView = true;
            popup.calculateRelativePosition = function () {
                return 'tr';
            };

            feature.popup = popup;
            map.addPopup(popup);
        },
        'featureunselected': function(evt) {
            var feature = evt.feature;
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            feature.popup = null;
        }
    });



map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
//create selector
    var selector = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(vectorLayer,{
        hover:true,
        autoActivate:true
    });

    map.addControl(selector);
```

//create vector features

```
var feature =

 new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(
                            new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( unit.lon,unit.lat ).transform(epsg4326, projectTo),
                            {name:unit.name, address:unit.address, speed:unit.speed},
                            {externalGraphic: '/assets/admin/layout/img/avatar/' + unit.id + '.png', graphicHeight: 74, graphicWidth: 74, graphicXOffset:-18, graphicYOffset:-71  }
                    );
                    feature.id = unit.id;
                    vectorLayer.addFeatures(feature);
```

If I change `featureselected` with `featureclicked`, popups are shown well but they don't disappear as I wish. What is the problem here?

Additionally, can I give an offset to the popup? And how?